# HTML5 required field but not a 'submit' type of button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field:-

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
           Name: 
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 28px; width: 383px;">
           <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Name" required>
      </div>
</div>
```

The submit button in my form :-

```
<button data-ng-click="addNew(currentUser)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add New User</button>
```

is of type=button... that is because I want to avoid a post-back.... However this is causing issues with how the required field is supposed to behave in my HTML5 code.... Does this mean I have to implement custom error checking in Javascript? If so can anyone show my how I can do that, because I alread have a click function defined on my submit button...

Comment: You can change type to submit and in addNew function return false, in that case browser doesn't send post in standart way.
Or via jQuery - e.preventDefault();

Comment: Add ngSubmit directive and `novalidate` attribute on the form. Then use normal Angular validation approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this piece of code:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">Name: </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 28px; width: 383px;">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button data-ng-click="addNew(currentUser)" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add New User</button>
</form>
```

And JavaScript function:

```
function validate() {
    // validation logic or whatever you want
    return true; // return false; in case of validation error
}
```

As @dfsq mentioned in comment, `novalidate` attribute and manual validation on `Angular` site is preffered way to do it clean and elegant.